# TypeError: argument of type 'Mock' is not iterable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How could I mock an iterable item?

In trying to test this method:

```
    def convert_time_field(klass, field, default=None):
        time = GrapheneHelper.get_json_field(klass, field, default)

        if time is None:
            return None
        else:
            return iso8601.parse_date(time)
```

My first test returns this error: `TypeError: argument of type 'Mock' is not iterable`

```
    def test_convert_time_field(self):
        """ Return YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:FF in iso8601 format """
        time = '2017-09-18T23:09:57Z'
        expected_time = '2017-09-18 23:09:57+00:00'
        mock_klass = Mock()
        self.assertEqual(GrapheneHelper.convert_time_field(mock_klass, time, default=None), expected_time)
```

What am I misunderstanding about mocks in this case?

Comment: I think you want a `MagicMock`. Per the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-a-generator-method

Comment: I'm using python 2.7... I think it's supported - will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test ended up changing to this:

```
@patch('myModule.myClass')
def test_convert_time_field(self, mock_klass):
    """ Return YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:FF in iso8601 format """
    mock_klass.json = {'time_field': '2017-09-18T23:09:33'}
    expected_time = iso8601.parse_date('2017-09-18 23:09:33')

    self.assertEqual(GrapheneHelper.convert_time_field(mock_klass, field='time_field', default=None), expected_time)
```